# A Postapocalyptic Medieval Frontier Town

Tags: internal-consistency, cities, post-apocalypse

In a postapocalyptic scenario, it took man quite some time to pick up the pieces and rebuild civilization from scratch.  The largest and best thus far is categorized by the settlement hierarchy as "city", a population between 100,000 and 300,000.

In this postapocalyptic scenario, the average American town is a mix of the following:

- **Medieval**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- **19th Century Frontier**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The ideal postapocalyptic American town is a midway between both styles.  But is this midway compatible?  Could a cultural fusion between the two styles happen organically, or would the result be just lazy hodgepodge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The US is a pretty big place with several different ecosystems. Considering most civilizations before common trade and globalization relied heavily on the resources available in the locations where it's based the clothing and construction would reflect that.

1) How far behind, technologically, is this post-apocalyptic civilization? (how available is glass, paper, light, water, fuel, etc.)

2) What kind of construction resources does it have nearby (color and strength of rock, wood, mud, etc.)?

3) How is the weather? What animal life exists? What is the soil like? (food and clothing will depend a lot on this)

4) What kind of organization does society have? (more communal could lead to less chimneys, more public spaces, for example)

5) What events lead to the point where that city would be now? And how could such a big city (by both Frontier and Medieval standards) support itself?

Medieval architecture is the result of hundreds of years of settlement. Frontier is largely the result of temporary events. The fusion between both could happen it they had different origins (more developed civilization invaded by nomadic one) but it seems, at the very least, unlikely. The more stable, long term settlement, society would tend to envelop, culturally, the temporary one (even if invaded). This mix would be a short lived one.

Comment: Regarding the first question:  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37563/a-generation-of-revelation